# Can't play cached audio file Android java

Tags: java, android, audio, media

I want to download, cache and play an audio file from the network. I managed to download and save it to the context.getCacheDir(). Absolute path is "/data/user/0/org.kimp.mustep/cache/floor_01/entrance_ru.mp3".

When I try to play it with a MediaPlayer's object the app crashes.

There is some ways I tried to do that:

```
MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();
FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(target);
player.setDataSource(inputStream.getFD());
inputStream.close();
player.setAudioAttributes(new AudioAttributes.Builder()
    .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_MUSIC)
    .build());
player.prepare();
player.start();
```

and

```
MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();
player.setDataSource(activity.getBaseContext(), Uri.fromFile(target));
player.prepare();
player.start();
```

*target* is a File object with the mp3

And every time I have an error:

```
error (1, -2147483648)
java.io.IOException: Prepare failed.: status=0x1
```

Comment: Perhaps the download is corrupted. Have you tried copying the file off the device/emulator and testing it elsewhere?

Comment: @CommonsWare the file is correct. It sounds perfectly on my computer